# Magento custom css overridden by parent css - using local.xml

Tags: css, magento, themes

I have a simple local.xml that attempts to include a custom wc_styles.css in my head block, to apply for all pages in my Magento site.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <file>css/wc_styles.css</file>
        </action>

        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/wc_styles.css</stylesheet></action>

    </reference>


    </default>
</layout>
```

When viewing the source of my website, my wc_styles.css is being included above all the parent themes css files (all within the html head tag), so my custom css rules get cancelled out basically.

What is the proper way of getting a custom css to work?

**Edit Note:**
I'm merely trying to make look & feel changes to the Magento 1.9 RWD theme.
I've created the folders for my subtheme at

\app\design\frontend\wc\default

\skin\frontend\wc\default

My local.xml is placed at:
\app\design\frontend\warecompare\default\layout

My wc_styles.css is placed at
\skin\frontend\warecompare\default\css

This is what the source code of my site looks like where u see my wc_styles.css appearing above the parents styles.css

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://localhost/mg1/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://localhost/mg1/js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/base/default/css/et_advancedcompare/noreload.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/wc/default/css/wc_styles.css" media="all" />
<!-- big heap of javascript includes here-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600" />
<!--[if  (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles-ie8.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/madisonisland-ie8.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mg1/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/madisonisland.css" media="all" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What is your custom module name ?

Comment: Hi @programmer_rkt , thanks for ur help on the previous post, was hoping to hear from u  :) I don't have a custom module. I'm just trying to customize the look of the magento 1.9 installed rwd theme, which i've subthemed into my own theme directories.

Comment: @aDvo Have you check http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes

Comment: @aDvo Check this module, this mat helpful to you https://github.com/drewhunter/ItemPosition

Comment: Hi Meenakshi, i've seen the post on alanstorm, and yeah i basically followed the same steps. He doesn;t talk about using the local.xml method of adding css files. But there is some nice info on Magento 2 there. As for the ItemPosition module, ill try it only as a last resort. There are so many websites that say adding css files via local.xml works. One example is http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/ . For me it works, but my css gets included at the beginning instead of the end of the head section :(

Comment: I seem to have a working solution from here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/how-to-change-order-of-stylesheets-and-js-in-magento-and-add-multiple-css-js-fil
....
This solution basically requires a removeItem and addItem in local.xml for each of the parent theme css file, so u basically reorder the CSS files in the head section.. Don't know if this is the best solution

Answer (score 7):

Magento will process `local.xml` file after processing every layout files. So if you want to extend something or need to remove something, `local.xml` file can be used.

Normally the css files that are included through `layout.xml` will load at last. Suppose you are trying to load different css files through different layout files. See the demo

```
LAYOUT FILE         STYLE NAME          HANDLER USED
-----------------------------------------------------
layout1.xml     =>  style1.css      =>  default
                =>  style2.css      =>  cms_page

layout2.xml     =>  style3.css      =>  default

layout3.xml     =>  style4.xml      =>  default
                =>  style5.xml      =>  cms_page


local.xml       =>  style6.xml      =>  default

Note: layout files are shown in the loaded order in Magento.
```

Here as you can see `local.xml` file is loaded at last. But it adds `style6.css` using a handler `default`. Please note that some of other layout files that are loaded above `local.xml` file also uses some other handlers. Here `layout3.xml` and `layout1.xml` uses `cms_page` handler to add some css files. Of course those css files only going to load when a cms page is used.

So suppose we loaded a page that uses cms page inside it. Example is home page of Magento. So the order of layout handles there for

```
ORDER OF LAYOUT HANDLE INVOKES
----------------------------------
        default
        cms_page

Note: Ignores other layout handlers that are using to load 
      home page of magento for the sake of simplicity
```

Due to this, for the above depicted scenario, styles will loaded in this format

```
ORDER OF STYLES LOADING
------------------------
style1.css
style3.css
style4.css

style6.css (style that we added through local.xml)

style2.css
style5.css
```

### Why this order

Magento first consider `default` handler. Then it will add css files that are specified under `default` handler  from  layout files. Layout files will be processed in the order they are loaded. After loaded all css files that are added through `default` handler, magento now consider `cms_page` handler and the process continues. So in our case, above css file order will generate and will load them in that order.

### Specific to this problem

Here it seems that `styles.css` is added after your css file. This will not happen normally. That is because `styles.css` is added via `page.xml` file and through `default` handler. So it will loaded first before your css file loaded. So there must some wierd thing happens in your case for sure.

**Special NOte**: You dont want use this code

```
 <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/wc_styles.css</stylesheet></action>
```

in your local.xml file.  This is enough

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <file>css/wc_styles.css</file>
        </action>
    </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write all that out Rajeev. this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with how Magento's RWD theme in 1.9 adds stylesheets: using conditional comments.

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/madisonisland.css</name>
    <params/>
    <if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if> <!-- SEE THIS? -->
</action>
```

It turns out Magento inserts stylesheets that don't have conditional comments first.

So, long story short, a way to overcome this is to use "empty" conditional comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_css</type>
                <name>css/tweaks.css</name>
                <params/>
                <if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Simon Sprankel wrote an in-depth article about this specific issue here: http://www.coderblog.de/magento-1-9-infinite-theme-inheritance-child-css-not-rendered-last/